# vim - change cursorline per filetype

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I created a filetype fitting my needs, and added a syntax file corresponding to it.

I use the syntax file to do some very specific highlighting using `ctermbg`, but the usual `CursorLine` I use is having also a `ctermbg` set. This is annoying as I lose my highlighting when the cursor goes over a line.

Thus I added to my syntax file: `hi CursorLine ctermbg=none guibg=none cterm=underline gui=underline`. Problem: it changes it in every buffer (and generally I don't like (read: hate) underlined cursorline when I code)!

Is it possible to make the cursorline change only in the current buffer (through the syntax file)? Or is it necessarily tied to all buffers at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

you could add cursorline for specific buffer, it's probably not the best solutions but you could try

```
augroup CursorLine
   au!
   au VimEnter,WinEnter,BufWinEnter * setlocal cursorline
   au WinLeave * setlocal nocursorline
augroup END
```